# Is There a Function Like "pthread_getcancelstate"?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

The Linux Pthread Library includes 2 functions to set a threads' cancel state and cancel type:

- `int pthread_setcancelstate(int state, int *oldstate)`
- `int pthread_setcanceltype(int type, int *oldtype)`

How can I receive those states and types? Is there a function like `pthread_getcancelstate` or `pthread_getcanceltype`? I searched on the Internet and I didn't found solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the functions [`pthread_setcancelstate()` and `pthread_setcanceltype()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_setcancelstate.html) return the old state via the argument list, you can call the functions to set the 'safe' state/type (`PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE` and `PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED`, I think), and if the old state/type was not the same, call the function a second time to reinstate the old state/type.  There doesn't seem to be a 'no-op' value for the new state/type.

```
int pthread_getcancelstate(int *oldstate)
{
    int dont_care;
    int rc = pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, oldstate);
    if (rc == 0 && *oldstate != PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE)
        rc = pthread_setcancelstate(*oldstate, &dont_care);
    return rc;
}

int pthread_getcanceltype(int *oldtype)
{
    int dont_care;
    int rc = pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED, oldtype);
    if (rc == 0 && *oldtype != PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED)
        rc = pthread_setcanceltype(*oldtype, &dont_care);
    return rc;
}
```

The other state is `PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE` and the other type is `PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS`.

The manual pages for these functions on macOS do say that it is permissible to pass a null pointer for the old state/type, so it would be possible to eliminate the `dont_care` variable on macOS.  However, neither the POSIX specification nor the manual page on (RHEL 7.4) Linux say that a null pointer is permissible.  The code above should work safely on both those platforms.

The code is also trespassing on the namespace reserved for use by the implementation — the implementation could choose to add either or both `pthread_getcancelstate()` or `pthread_getcanceltype()` (with the same or a different interface) and there'd be no option but to rename the functions shown above.  Adding the `_np` (non-portable) suffix might not help either; the implementation could choose to use the name with the suffix.

Comment: `dont_care` is not needed. These functions accept a null pointer for the old state argument.

Comment: The POSIX specification doesn't say that null pointers are permitted for the old values.  Interestingly, the macOS manual does say that null pointers are permitted, but the Linux (RHEL 7.4 checked) manual does not.

Comment: Wow, WTF - I somehow thought it did.

Comment: POSIX doesn't support null-pointers for this case, but Linux does. So yes you can put a NULL.